# classfiying singularities

Tags: complex-analysis

\begin{equation}
h(z)=\frac{z^2e^{\frac{1}{z^2+1}}}{\sin(z^2)}
\end{equation}
 It seems to me the function has essential singularity at $z=\mp i$

It is clear that $e^{\frac{1}{z}}$ has essential singularity at $z=0$. It can be seen that from Laurent expansion but i am not sure for essential singularities for $h(z)$

$z=0 , \lim_{z\to 0}h(z)=1$ so it is removable singularity.

How can we see essential singularities at $z=\mp i$ ?

Thank u for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> We consider the *[Laurent series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laurent_series)* expansion of $h(z)$ with center $z=i$.
>   \begin{align*}
> h(z)&=\frac{z^2}{\sin(z^2)}\exp\left(\frac{1}{z^2+1}\right)\\
> &=\frac{z^2}{\sin(z^2)}\exp\left(\frac{1}{2i}\cdot\frac{1}{z-i}-\frac{1}{2i}\cdot\frac{1}{z+i}\right)\tag{1}\\
> &=h_1(z)\exp\left(\frac{1}{2i}\cdot\frac{1}{z-i}\right)\tag{2}\\
> &=h_1(z)\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\frac{1}{2i}\right)^n\frac{1}{n!}(z-i)^{-n}\tag{3}
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (1) we use a partial fraction decomposition to isolate the relevant part.
- In (2) we set $h_1(z)$ to
  \begin{align*}
  h_1(z):=\frac{z^2}{\sin(z^2)}\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2i}\cdot\frac{1}{z+i}\right)
  \end{align*}
  which is *[analytic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_function)* in a neighborhood of $z=i$.
- In (3) we see that $z=i$ is an essential singularity of $\exp\left(\frac{1}{2i}\cdot\frac{1}{z-i}\right)$ and so of $h(z)$.

In the same way we can show that $z=-i$ is an essential singularity of $h(z)$.